# How can I create an anchor point corresponding to a specific line in multi-line text using TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have objects with multiple lines of text, and I'd like to draw an arrow from a particular line to another object.  How can I create anchors for particular lines?

For example, how can I draw the red line below without using `yshift`?

```
\documentclass[letter]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[align=left] (text)
  {Hello\\
  World!};
  \draw[->] (1cm,1cm) -- (text.mid east);
  \draw[->,red] (1cm,1cm) -- ([yshift=1.2em] text.mid east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Hello world example]

Comment: Create two nodes at the first place! For example `\node(H){Hello}(H.south)node[below](W){World};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tikzmark` `\subnode` is probably the easiest way. At least, it is the easiest one I can think of.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
  \node [align=left] (text)
  {\subnode{a}{Hello}\\
  World!};
  \draw[->] (1cm,1cm) -- (text.mid east);
  \draw[->,red] (1cm,1cm) -- (a -| text.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: red non-shift]

Comment: Also important to note that without `remember picture` tikz never reaches a fixed point!  Also note the use of `tikzmark` library.

Comment: @EdMcMan Yes, the `remember picture` is vital here. Otherwise, as you say, it will never settle.

Answer (score 4):

How about multi-part nodes?

(see p.726 of `pgfman.pdf`)

I added the borders via the `draw` option for emphasis, just remove that line if you don't want the frame lines.

You can pass two arguments to the `style 2 args` (as the name implies). I have used this for specifying the number of split boxes (the `#1` for the `rectangle split parts` parameter) and for the width of the text (the `#2` for the `text width` parameter).

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    multinode/.style 2 args = {                                                     
        draw,
        rectangle split,
        rectangle split parts=#1,
        align=left,
        text width=#2,
    },
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm]
    \coordinate (ref) at (1.5cm,1.5cm);
    \node[multinode={2}{4em}] (text)
        {
            \nodepart{one}
            Hello
            \nodepart{two}
            World!
        };
    \draw[->]     (ref) -- (text.one east);
    \draw[->,red] (ref) -- (text.two east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: result]

---

**EDIT:**

Slightly different version with left-alignment without having to specify the width and which will will have a minimum height for empty cells (just playing around a bit).

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    multinode/.style = {                                                     
        draw,
        rectangle split,
        rectangle split parts=#1,
        rectangle split empty part height=2ex,
        rectangle split part align=left,
    },
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm]
    \coordinate (ref) at (1.5cm,1.5cm);
    \node[multinode=4] (text)
        {
            \nodepart{one}
            Hello
            \nodepart{two}
            World!
            \nodepart{three}
            Again!
        };
    \draw[->]     (ref) -- (text.one east);
    \draw[->,red] (ref) -- (text.two east);
    \draw[->,blue] (ref) -- (text.three east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:[image: result 2]

Comment: Another good solution!